# How to Register a Spatial View when ArcSDE is direct connect only?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, direct-connect, sdelayer

I have an ArcSDE 10.0 set up with MS SQL 2008 R2 Database, on direct connect. There is no service running, nor installed.

I have created a spatial view built on a couple of tables. I have followed the steps given in 
[Creating a spatial view in SQL Server using SQL and registering it](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002q000000r3000000)

The View can now been seen in MS SQL Server management studio. It is also seen in ArcCatalog as a table.

Now I need to register it with ArcSDE, so that it is seen as a featureClass.
This requires that I run the `sdelayer -o register` command.
The problem is that since there is no service installed, I cannot run the command.

What is the solution in this case? How do I register this spatial view so that it appears as a layer to ArcGIS?

Comment: Are you asking about the `-i` parameter?  For an Oracle DB, this worked for me: `sdelayer -o register -l  XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX,SHAPE -G 2269 -t SDO_GEOMETRY -C XXX_ID,USER  -e ns -u XXXX -p XXXX -i sde:oracle11g:XXXX.XXXXX`, but I had to set an SDEHOME (e.g.  `c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop`).

Comment: @JayCummins: can you please put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would specify the direct connection string in the `-i` parameter.

For an Oracle DB, this worked for me: sdelayer -o register -l XXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX,SHAPE -G 2269 -t SDO_GEOMETRY -C XXX_ID,USER -e ns -u XXXX -p XXXX -i sde:oracle11g:XXXX.XXXXX, but I had to set an SDEHOME (e.g. c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop).

For a SQL Server DB, you would use `sde:sqlserver:<instance_name>` (looked up from [Direct connections from ArcSDE commands to a geodatabase in SQL Server](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002q0000003m000000))

Now that I'm looking at the [Oracle direct connection help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002n00000039000000), it looks like you can specify the SDEHOME in the connection string(e.g. `sde:oracle11g:XXXX.XXXXX;SDEHOME=c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop`).  But I've never done it this way and I only see it in the Oracle help, so I'm not sure if it works for other databases.

Comment: It does work for other databases; You don't even need to set the SDEHOME.

Answer (score 0):

This article sort of implies you can install JUST the SDE Admin commands using the app server installer:
http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39857